# Stripe subscription with fixed monthly renewal date

Tags: api, stripe-payments

I want fixed subscription invoice date on my stripe subscriptions. Currently it takes 30days in each month and If I create a subscription on 1st, next invoice comes on 30th but it should be 1st for every month. Here is my code-

```
$subscription = $stripe->subscriptions->create([
        'customer' => $customerID,
        'items' => $items,
        'add_invoice_items' => $invoiceitems,
        'payment_behavior' => 'default_incomplete',
        'expand' => ['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],
        'trial_end' => $startdate,
        //'cancel_at' => $enddate,
        'proration_behavior' => 'always_invoice',
        'billing_cycle_anchor' => $startdate
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see in your code snippet that you are using the `billing_date_anchor`.  The [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-billing_cycle_anchor) state

> Determines the date of the first full invoice, and, for plans with `month` or `year` intervals, the day of the month for subsequent invoices.

Based on that here are two things you should try.

1. Verify the [`price.recurring` attribute](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/object#price_object-recurring) has your prices recurring with `interval`  set to `"month"` and `interval_count` set to `1`.
2. Ensure the `$startdate` value passed in is anchored to your timezone.

Comment: $price = $stripe->prices->create([
              'unit_amount' => $productPrice,
              'currency' => 'aed',
              'recurring' => ['interval' => 'month'],
              'product' => $productID,
            ]);

Comment: interval is alreay set to month

Comment: and startdate is selected by user. I am just adding 30day in selected date -         $delivryDate = strtotime($_POST['ywcdd_delivery_date']);
$startdate = $delivryDate + 24*60*1800;